# Give an example of a nonabelian group such that G/Z(G) is...

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

A) abelian;
B) nonabelian;

Not sure here.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried? For example, what are some nonabelian groups that you know of? What are their centers? What can you say about the quotient?

Comment: Well, try *any* nonabelian group and you should have an example for at least one of the tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Consider the question for the smallest non-abelian groups, which are the symmetric group $S_3$, the dihedral group $D_4$ and the quaternion group.

Comment: I have already used D3, since D3 is nonabelian for the second case; and I am not allowed to use S3, as required by my professor. I am struggling finding the first case; where I have a nonabelian group, G such that G/Z(G) is abelian

Comment: @Arnold: $S_3$ and $D_3$ are isomorphic. Did you check the quaternion group?

Answer (score 1):

A) Consider a dihedral group of symmetries of a triangle.  The elements are rotation about its center by $2\pi /4$ radians : $o, o^2, o^3$, reflection about a line through it's center and one of its vertices: $l$ with $l^2 = 1$.  Then $ol \neq lo$, check that on paper.  So it's not abelian.

According to [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group), $lol = o^{-1} = o^2$, together with $|\langle o \rangle|= 3$ and $l^2 =1$ is a presentation for the group.  So then let's calculate it's order:

It's elements are all strings over $o,l$, st $l$ appears only once consecutively and the preceding presentation rules are adhered to.   Then strings of length $1$ are:

$o, l$

Strings of length $2$ are:

$o^2, ol, lo = o^2l$

Strings of length $3$ are:
$olo$

(checking each binary number in $o, l$)

Strings of length $4$ are:
(using irreducible strings of length 3)
There are none.

So counting up we have $|D_3|$ = 6.

Well any quotient groups not isomorphic to $D_3$ are clearly abelian then, since $6$ is sufficiently small. Prove that.